# Get height and length using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a string.

```
GB-1210 •  40″W x 80 1/4″L x 30 1/4″H
```

I need to get width, length and height from this string using regular expression.

Using this regular expression, I can find width But I cannot find length and height

```
(\d+\.?\d*)W
```

Comment: What's expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need "1210" from "GB-1210" you can use this regular expression:

```
(?:\w+-|\s?x\s?)([^″]+)
```

Otherwise "GB-1210" can be a Chinese standard. 
So probably it would be great for you to use this:

```
(\d+(?: \d+\/\d+)?)″
```

Also you can catch the measurement direction:

```
(\d+(?: \d+\/\d+)?)″(\w)
```

or

```
(?:\w+-|\s?x\s?)([^″]+)″(\w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your regex engine/tool supports capture groups, you may just continue with your current approach:

```
^.*?\b(\d+(?: \d+\/\d+)?)″W.*?\b(\d+(?: \d+\/\d+)?)″L.*?\b(\d+(?: \d+\/\d+)?)″H.*$
```

The width, height, and length would be available in the first, second, and third capture groups.

### Demo